# Remove & UPDATE all junk characters by REGEXP_REPLACE using FOR loop

Tags: for-loop, plsql, sql-update, regexp-replace

I have a table contains 10+ columns some data contains junks like arrows,®,¼,â... I want to remove & UPDATE all junks from all columns with **REGEXP_REPLACE** using **FOR** loop in **UPDATE** statement.

**DATA**:

```
I AM â€˜USERâ€

?®Name

â€¢ We
```

I have to write a UPDATE query using FOR loop to check all columns:

```
update table_name
set    column_name = regexp_replace(column_name,'[^[a-z,A-Z,0-9,[:space:]]]*','')
where  regexp_like(column_name, '[^[:print:][:space:]]' );
```

Comment: Looping through columns isn't easy or efficient in PL/SQL, if that's what you are trying to do. If you want to apply the same function to multiple columns then you could write one, either as a separate PL/SQL unit or inline using `with function cleanup...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a pl/sql for loop for this, just an update should be fine.

```
UPDATE 
  table_name 
  SET 
  column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]','')
 WHERE regexp_like(column_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]' );
```

for multiple columns, just change the update statement.

```
create table weird_chars (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint weird_chars_id_pk primary key,
    column1                        varchar2(100 char),
    column2                        varchar2(100 char),
    column3                        varchar2(100 char)
)
;

-- load data
 
insert into weird_chars (
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
) values (
    'I AM â€˜USERâ€',
    '?®Name',
    'Just normal text'
);
-- load data
 
insert into weird_chars (
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
) values (
    'Just normal text',
    'Just normal text',
    'Just normal text'
);

UPDATE 
  weird_chars 
  SET 
  column1 = REGEXP_REPLACE(column1,'[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]',''),
  column2 = REGEXP_REPLACE(column2,'[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]',''),
  column3 = REGEXP_REPLACE(column3,'[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]','')
  
 WHERE 
   (regexp_like(column1, '[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]' ) OR 
    regexp_like(column2, '[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]' ) OR 
    regexp_like(column3, '[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]' )
   );

1 row updated
```

Comment: Yes, but I have to UPDATE all columns with a single expression. So by FOR loop it has to go to every single column in table to check and replace junk character.

Comment: You can update any number of columns in a single update statement - no need for pl/sql, check my answer.